# Remote SSH commands responses do not appear in browser from CGI

Tags: linux, ssh, cgi

I have a simple CGI page (running on linux, apache) that grabs some responses from remote servers. When I manually run the script (from a terminal) it echos the complete web-page correctly, including all remote responses. But when I open the browser, the responses are not there!

Here's my script for reference.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html class="background"><head><title>My Page"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo ""

echo "<h2>Local Uptime :</h2>"
echo `uptime` #Local commands work normally

echo "<h2>Remote Uptime: </h2>"
echo `/usr/bin/ssh root@remote-server "uptime"`

echo "</body></html>"
```

Of course, I previously set keys for password-less logins.

Comment: When you run it manually, are you running it as the same user that your web server runs as?  For example, `sudo -u apache YOUR_SCRIPT`

Comment: "*... the responses are not there!*" All responses are missing or only the remote ones?

Comment: only the remote responses are missing ..

Comment: @twm you are definitely right, the user apache has no certified keys. I was trying the script using root user. I followed this post to copy ssh keys to the remote server  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ssh-key-for-apache-user-333325/ Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure selinux is turned off (or set the correct options for the web browser to execute ssh).

```
cat /selinux/enforce
```

If it's 1 set it to 0 as root

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Comment: I do not have selinux enabled!